# Firebase Auto Index creation is not working anymore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Firebase has a [nice feature](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#create_a_missing_index_through_an_error_message) whereby if there isn't an index for a query then it sends a link in the error message which you can click and it will create that index for you, I have relied on that feature and didn't have to manually create it earlier. For a few days, it seems it has stopped working, now when I click the link it doesn't do anything. I also then went on and manually created the index with the same fields that are in the query, too Firebase complained that I need the query.

**Error in console.log:**

[image]

**Manage Index screen in Firestore:**

[image]

Is anyone else facing this issue?

1. Firebase should auto create the index when I click on the link in error.
2. After manually creating the index  firebase should not complain.

Comment: The generated link only works if your the account you use with Firebase console is the primary account logged in. If it is in the second or third slot, then the link won't work. You can check this by looking for `/u/0` and `?authuser=0` in the URL of a google service like the console or Gmail. If you see a different number, you will either need to set up a new browser profile with the right account or log out of all of your Google accounts and relog them in, with the developer account first.

Comment: Thanks @samthecodingman, it seems like it was a caching problem. I logged out of the browser  & deleted cache. That solved the issue.  The strange thing is I have never used another user, regardless the issue is now resolved. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @samthecodingman already mentioned in his comment, you won't be able to create the necessary index if the account you're logged in inside the Firebase Console doesn't match the one in your app. To solve this, you should either log out and log in again with the right account, or you can set up a new browser profile with the correct account.

Comment: Thanks @alex-mamo I logged out , deleted cache, and logged back in and it now works. As I mentioned to @ samthecodingman I only have 1 user per chrome profile so its strange but regardless it worked. Thanks!